# Count with a grouping columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

My request is simple, I count the differents columns of my table.
The first query count the columns brought by the subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3)
FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM mytable
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 500000
) AS rq
```

The Limit clause is essential in my use case.

This request works very well for counting singles columns, but I need also count a grouping of columns (a lot of not null columns instead of a single one).

So I need the result of

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS mygroup
FROM mytable
WHERE (field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL)
```

But in the current 500000 (LIMIT clause) lines from the first query.

How can I do that ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3),
       SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM mytable t
      WHERE ...
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 500000
     ) rq;
```