# Should I certainly use SUM() for conditional aggregation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I seen before professional programmer use `SUM()` *(not `COUNT()`)* for conditional aggregation. For example take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171459/count-with-a-grouping-columns/38171504#38171504):

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3),
       SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM mytable t
      WHERE ...
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 500000
     ) rq;
```

Is there any specific reason? Actually tested it and `COUNT()` also works perfectly fine when there is a condition. So what's the difference between:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

And

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

In other word, Why sometimes `COUNT()` is used and sometimes else `SUM()` in the query above *(first query)*?

Comment: Are u sure you get the same result? Because even 0 values are counted in the COUNT query, but not in SUM

Answer (score 3):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

And

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Are two different things and I donno how you get the same answer (might be because of the data set you are using). But in this setting its better to use COUNT but you have change code a bit

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
```

However i don't think there will be a high performance impact by any of them.

Comment: please explain why you are stating it would be better to use count in this setting,  I don't see any reason why SUM() or COUNT() would be a preferred method other than personal preference and personally I would actually prefer sum.  any time you can remove the nulls (or unknowns value in SQL) I feel your code and intent is clearer.

Comment: @Matt I use cont and sum interchangeably as I believed there is no performance difference. However you should always use what shows your intention. In this case what he need is a count. Putting a sum here Will reduce the readability as reader might think why we need a sum here, and count aligns with his goal and rest of his query. I have practical experience why you should not use sum when your intention is to count

Answer (score 1):

@Malinga explained that there really isn't a difference to the methods and I agree with him.  I do have a personal preference to use SUM() only because NULLs are considered UNKNOWN in SQL and have a lot of rules/nuances to know so any time I can eliminate I prefer to do so.

A quick note if you don't put an ELSE statement in NULL is implied when conditions are not met. So.

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

CAN BE WRITTEN

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
```

However, concerning performance I would be curious about 2 things.

1 the order by in your inner select isn't necessary and would just add a task for the sql engine to do.  So you might improve your performance by removing it. Note just choose the sum or the count method whichever is preferred.

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3),
       SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM mytable t
      WHERE ...
      LIMIT 500000
     ) rq;
```

Next and I know this will seem weird but the LIMIT could actually decrease your performance too depending on how many records are in the table, indexes, and a few more things.  So you if you really want the results for the entire table you could just write your query as such.

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3),
       SUM(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN field4 IS NOT NULL AND field5 IS NOT NULL AND field6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM mytable t
WHERE ...
;
```

Comment: @Matt I agree with your view to use sum when null is not preferable. Thanks for the input. But if you see his whole query is written around null. If he is going to replace null, that mean all most full query will be rewritten. And here for count null is given in the query and that else is not needed as you suggest. Edited the query